# Splitting shapefile into multiple shapefiles without particular attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, splitting

I would like to split a shapefile made up of approximately 8200 elements into five having an equal number of elements. I don't want to base this division on an attribute. There is a simple way to do that in QGIS?

Comment: What geometry type? What's the spatial distribution (clustering?) of the features? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. The records have a point geometry. I don't care about the geographic relations amonst them. For me it is ok just to select the first 8474/5 elements, then another group of equal number, ect.ect. I tried to do it manually, but it is very hard and not efficient. The problem is working with the "selection by expression" function, I think. I can select by field, but as I mention, existing fields do not help me.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a new attribute field which bins the 8474 elements into 5 bins:

bin_size = 8474/5, or approx. 1750 elements per bin.

Go to field calculator and generate a new integer field called 'bin' with this expression:

```
ceil(@row_number/1750)
```

If  you want it to be more dynamic, you can do this, which uses the size of the table as a parameter for the number of elements per bin. Replace 'fid' with the name of a different field if your table doesn't have a field named fid.

```
ceil(@row_number/(count('fid')/5))
```

[image]

Then use bin as the field to split by in the Split tool.

[image]

Comment: That is very usueful, many thanks.